# Finding longest common substring using Trie

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, trie

How can i find LCS (longest common substring) among two or more strings using trie ?

I have an idea like this -
suppose my first string is "abbcabdd".
then i will first insert "abbcabdd" in trie ,then "bbcabdd", then "bcabdd" .... , then "d"
and repeat this process for every string .

Then calculate the longest substring by traversing the trie.

but i think it is not efficient.
Is there any other improved method ?

Answer (score 4):

What you are describing is exactly a [suffix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) - Use an algorithm optimized to generate a suffix tree, and you will get your efficiency increased!

Note that there is an algorithm for building a suffix tree in `O(n)` (assuming a constant alphabet, of course).

Comment: thanks. yes i'm describing the suffix tree. my suffix tree implementation is fast enough but i'm worried about my algorithm of inserting n strings for every string where n= stringLength.

Comment: @palatok: You can use the suffix tree builder algorithm - it will yield the same result, and is already researched and analyzed, no need to reinvent the wheel here. Creating a suffix tree is `O(n)`.